# Horror Episode #2: Not So Well

Tags: riddle, cipher

You get a call from an old friend to come to a pavilion in the woods that you and him camped out at as young teenagers. The reason being is that there was a well put in place a few months ago there. However, there has been many disappearances associated with the well. Being the brave soul you are, you decide to investigate.

The first thing you notice beside the blinding mist is a plaque on the well which is seen below.

FGTAK

FNUEA

OICFT

RFDIE

EANNG

All of a sudden you hear a ghoulish "WOOOO" from the hollow well. Intrigued, you look down only to see a disfigured woman jump out and attack you and drag you down into the well.

Once inside, you see all the missing people, some dead from starvation it seems, but the more recently MIA people are still okay. You see many pieces of silverware including spoons, knives, and salad tongs. On top of this pile is a note which says," Take one of these pieces of cutlery and use it on the woman to escape.". This note has puzzled these missing people, some of them to death. But being a keen puzzle solver, you may have a chance.

Keep all that you have seen throughout your investigation and find a way to escape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly full solution:

> Starting at G in the lower-right corner of the letters and reading up the columns right to left reveals the message: **GET A KNIFE AND CUT A FINGER OFF**.

I don't know yet if there are other clues in the text that lead you to that message, though.